# iPhone Objective C Image Upload to apache server

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios

The code I am using which is meant to upload an image to my apache server does not work. The PHP page returns "ERROR". The idea is to take it from the Photo Library then store it in a directory called photos.

Any suggestions on what is wrong with it. Thanks.

iPhone Code

```
-(IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *profile_image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self uploadImage:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profile_image, 1.0) filename:@"test.jpg"];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData filename:(NSString *)filename{


    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myurl.net/picture_upload.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Set the filename
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //append the image data
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    return ([returnString isEqualToString:@"OK"]);
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'photos/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check credentials for files?

Comment: the folder is 777 if thats what you mean

Comment: was the file uploaded to photos folder before moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738704/sending-multipart-post-from-ios-and-reading-parameters-in-php-post) helps.

You can also try sending the file using [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)