# objc POST file and string parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

I am trying to POST a file, and some string params to a .ashx page on my server from my iPad app using objc.

I have found lots of tutorials on how to post a file using objc, and I already have code to post strings. But I cant work out how to combine the two, so I can send multiple values in a single POST?

Could anyone help me out with an example or two? I am trying to avoid using 3rd party frameworks, so something using NSURLRequest would be preferred.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Show you code, and it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a multipart submission, with boundary strings, etc. Here's some helper code: https://github.com/Goles/SimpleHttpRequest from the answer to this question: [Sending multipart POST from iOS and reading parameters in PHP $_POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738704/sending-multipart-post-from-ios-and-reading-parameters-in-php-post)

Comment: perfect - took me a while to realise why my NSData wasnt outputting to a valid file once I saved it on the server, the problem was the NSData object in the NSDictionary was being made into a string, and then into NSData again, which was unnecessary, so I put in an if statement to detect whether it was a NSData, or NSString in the object and added it to the main NSData in the appropriate way.